# Using ASP.Net and Entity Framework: adding a child object in a 1:1 relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

This may be laziness on my part, but I couldn't find an easy example of this.

Referencing my favourite TV show Game of Thrones, my example is as follows:

```
Table Throne (ThroneID)
Table King (ThroneID)
```

Using Entity Framework 4, I have two tables that have a 1:1 relationship to each other.  In code, I want to associate a King to a Throne.  A Throne can have 0 or 1 Kings associated.  If it was 1:Many, I had the `Add()` method to create the association.  What do I use for 1:1?

(ok, I realize now my example is not the best... but in this example, the KingID will be the same as ThroneID to enforce the 1:1)

```
GameOfThronesContext context = new GameOfThronesContext();
Throne t = new Throne();
King k = new King();
t.Kings.Add(k);  // doesn't work because "Add" isn't available
context.Thrones.AddObject(t);
```

Comment: Looks like I answered my own question.  I wasn't sure if the association would be maintained at the time of saving, but I tested it and the following works.

You must assign the parent to the child, not the other way around.  This must cause the framework to add King as a child of Throne, but it isn't obvious.  I am probably still missing the equivalent assignment from the other direction, but I can't figure it out.  If anyone can confirm or deny it, I would appreciate the knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the solution below if for EF Code First 4.1, it shows how to design the two classes in order to have a relationshiop one-to-zero/one, the result will be:

- Throne{Id(PK), Name..}
- King {Id(PK,FK), Name..}

public class Throne
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual King King { get; set; }
    }

```
public class King
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Throne Throne { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship is then defined in the OnModelCreating of the context or in a configuration class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet< Throne> Thrones { get; set; }
    public DbSet< King> Kings { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        //We define the key for the King table
        modelBuilder.Entity< King>().HasRequired(x => x.Throne);
    }
}
```

You can then:

```
 var throne = new Throne(){Name = "First Throne"};
 var king = new King() { Name = "First King" };
 throne.King = king;
 context.Thrones.Add(throne);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thanks for the effort on answering the question, however your framing of the answer does not help me, unfortunately.  I was looking for an answer in the context of how MS sets up the business layer objects based on the data model (edmx), and I managed to answer my own question.   As I get more familiar with using it, I have since learned that I have a lot more to learn.

Comment: actually, rereading your solution and I didn't really understand it the first time I read it.  So this enhances the model so I can use the model the way I had originally intended - a better solution, tho maybe more maintenance in the long term.  Is there a feature option to select so the framework generates this without manually adding it?

Comment: The code above uses Ef Code first : you create your models first and then the database is created, the opposite of getting the classes generated from a db schema with the edmx. Have a look online for some documentation, here's a good start : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Updated to reflect OP's comments:

```
var t = new Throne {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    //...
    King = new King {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid()
        //...
    }
};

context.Thrones.Add(t);
context.SaveChanges();
```

EF 4.1 is smart enough to work out constraints.

Comment: My example wasn't the best, but this solution would violate key contstraints.  King is a child of Throne.  The ThroneID must exist first.  Also, this solution requires calling SaveChanges twice, which I could do, but I'm sure that the framework would allow for a process whereby you would only need to call it once.  I'm looking to know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

So I answered my own question: MS arranges it so that you must assign the parent to the child in this case.  The generated code from the Data Entity Framework does not create the ability to assign the child to the parent for some reason.  Took me a while to find it.  The following works:

```
GameOfThronesContext context = new GameOfThronesContext();
Throne t = new Throne();
King k = new King();
//t.Kings.Add(k);  // doesn't work because "Add" isn't available
k.Throne = t;  // this is made available by the framework
context.Thrones.AddObject(t);
```

That being said, george2giga shows how to enhance the model so that you can add a child to the  parent (I think) so that you can use `t.King = k;` the way I had wanted to in the first place which is a better solution.  Kudos.